# Java service with GUI tool

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, service

I have an application with GUI. GUI is used for settings management only. Now I need to turn this into Windows service. I thought of splitting my app into 2: service itself and GUI-tool for providing settings. Main problem is that I'm not sure, how this tools should "communicate". Settings are stored mostly in files, and after new settings applied, service should restart.
As for now, I thought of admin-tool sending few requests to service over TCP/IP, that also allows to control service from the network. Problem is that I need to hardcode, or use some text file, to set default port on which service would listen for admin-tool connections after it's installation.
May be there is any alternative solution, which is more suitable here?

Comment: What about Jetty + Procrun?

Comment: How about the service picking up any arbitary port for listening to admin tool connection and dump it to a file, which the admin tool can read. Slightly better approach than hard coding the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a service. If all you need in the communication layer is being able to stop and start the services, then you don't need to open a port and start listening. The system gives you means to do that with commands that you can run. you are talking about windows, so for example you can run the command "sc start MyServiceName" to start service "MyServiceName". there is also a command called "net" which allows you to start and stop services. These OS commands can be then called from java code in various ways that are available to execute external code.

here is a link that shows how to do that with sc command, check the accepted answer: [start-windows-service-from-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075098/start-windows-service-from-java)

here is another link that shows difference between two commands "sc" and "net": [net-start-service-and-sc-start-what-is-the-difference](https://superuser.com/questions/315166/net-start-service-and-sc-start-what-is-the-difference)

Note that "sc" supports starting services on remote machines: [simplest-way-to-restart-service-on-a-remote-computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266389/simplest-way-to-restart-service-on-a-remote-computer)

Comment: +1. In addition, JSmooth Java -> Exe Wrapper has some rudimentary Windows Service support: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html#N103CD

Comment: @Rekin Thanks. You add an important aspect which is the ability to use the facilities supplied by service wrapper libraries.

Comment: My next task would be to make this project work on linux, though I've never done that before. Will there be a great difference then?

Comment: yes because linux OS has different commands. I suggest you check this project from apache commons which can create service wrapper for both windows and linux. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/

Comment: just not to confuse: in my last comment, you use an external library. it helps you making service from your application for windows and linux. as for interaction with the services, you can either run system commands directly, or see what this library offers. If you choose to run commands directly, you need to search how you interact with services on linux.