# Start Wildfly / JBoss from GUI

Tags: jboss, server, wildfly

how is it possible to start JBoss (Wildfly) application server from a GUI ?
I would like to implement a own GUI like XAMPP.
Only a "start" - Button and "stop" - Button.

Maybe I have to start the .bat - file?
There is a start and stop .bat available, but how can I do this in JAVA? To implement a GUI is not the case. The question is to start / stop the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to execute the batch file by passing them to the `cmd` shell.

If you are developing the script for windows you can have a field that points the JBossAS/Wildfly's Home directory(or can read it from the JBOSS_HOME if its set), and then in the Java Code execute the .bat file in the following way:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start standalone.bat")`;

Preferably you can also use the `[ProcessBuilder][1]` API to create a new process.

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application) for some helpful pointers

Comment: thanks. How is it possible to save the setting that Wildfly start as an Service? So everytime if the PC is up and running the Wildfly server starts automaticly ?

Comment: You can create a wildfly service by running the .bat file present in `bin\service` folder and then query it from the Java code to check if the service is running or not

Comment: Please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075098/start-windows-service-from-java to find out how to query that a service is running or not in java

Comment: Hm this is not working, but I got also no error message?   String desktopPath = "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\Software\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\bin\\standalone.bat";
   
   String [] cmds = new String [1];
   cmds[0] = desktopPath;
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
   p.isAlive();